# Rails uninitialized constant ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am just setting up action mailer and this one is default, Just after generating the mailer it seems the issue here is with ActionMailer itself

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'from@example.com'
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

```
 uninitialized constant ActionMailer
[98c7cc1a-bc46-4d7c-864e-0fc062867062] /Users/priya/fs-statuspage-api/app/mailers/application_mailer.rb:1:in `<main>'
/Users/priya/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0@fs-statuspage-api/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
/Users/priya/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0@fs-statuspage-api/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
/Users/priya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:30:in `require'
/Users/priya/fs-statuspage-api/app/mailers/subscriber_mailer.rb:1:in `<main>'
/Users/priya/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0@fs-statuspage-api/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
/Users/priya/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0@fs-statuspage-api/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
/Users/priya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:30:in `require'
/Users/priya/fs-statuspage-api/app/controllers/subscribers_controller.rb:20:in `create'
/Users/priya/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0@fs-statuspage-api/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.2/lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
/Users/priya/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0@fs-statuspage-api/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.2/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:215:in `process_action'
/Users/priya/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0@fs-statuspage-api/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.2/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:53:in `process_action'
/Users/priya/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0@fs-statuspage-api/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.2/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in process_action'
/Users/priya/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0@fs-statuspage-api/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:107:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/priya/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0@fs-statuspage-api/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.2/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:233:in `process_action'
/Users/priya/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0@fs-statuspage-api/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.2/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
/Users/priya/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0@fs-statuspage-api/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.2/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:67:in `block in process_action'
/Users/priya/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0@fs-statuspage-api/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `block in instrument'
/Users/priya/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0@fs-statuspage-api/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
/Users/priya/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0@fs-statuspage-api/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `instrument'
/Users/priya/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0@fs-statuspage-api/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.2/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:66:in `process_action'
/Users/priya/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0@fs-statuspage-api/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.2/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:259:in `process_action'
```

Comment: Is the `actionmailer` gem loaded when the application boots? Does `Gemfile` list individual gems intead of `rails`? Does `config/application.rb` cherry-pick Rails components instead of loading them all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you forget to require `action_mailer` in `config/application.rb`

Comment: yes, that how the issue was fixed. This is not even mentioned in the documentation